# SQL Injection from Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

We have a web application that occasionally receives web request that we detect as attempts to inject SQL code, from Google virtual servers (Compute Engine).

I was asked to find a way to identify who is responsible for said machines, so that we can take the corresponding legal actions on our part, or at least, confirm that Google shut down those servers.

What I need is to find a way to communicate with Google, by email or chat, but I haven't found information about it.

**EDIT 1**:
I have tried to communicate with Google to indicate the information I am looking for, but the only contact available in my case is with the billing department, which could not confirm that they will give me that information if I buy a technical assistance package. On the other hand, I understand that this package is to review requirements of the applications that you own, but in my case I am looking for legal information.
What was recommended to me was to enter the corresponding application in

https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_report?hl=en

but I have not received a response for weeks.
I am disappointed in Google, especially because of the importance of computer security.

I will keep searching information.

Comment: you might need to ask on here https://cloud.google.com/support-hub/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all information concerning Tech support, phone support and Chat support in your [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat?_ga=2.250536773.-2144609425.1568046180). Also, this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/support/) shows different supports based on your support role or package.